# Network problem in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I booted my pen-drive with Kali Linux, when I open live Kali Linux with that bootable pen-drive, my system is not connecting to any network neither wired nor wireless, so please help me to get  network connection.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to check whether you got the drivers for your network interface controller or not, this is a very common issue with Kali. You can also read this article [Network issues](http://docs.kali.org/installation/troubleshooting-wireless-driver-issues).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your kali is upgraded and as far as i know there is little bit problem in networking of **kernel 3.14**.

Sometimes kernel can't find the wireless hardware. I suggest you booted your pen-drive with **updated kali** (its include 3.18 kernel version) or use net through LAN.